# Using KPI's to count Document Sets in SharePoint 2013

Tags: document-set, kpi

I am using Document Sets to track multiple documents as a "case", and would like to use the SharePoint KPI's to track total numbers of cases.

I can get the KPIs to count the total documents inside of a document set, but cannot get them to recognize the Document Set itself.

Does anyone know a way to tell SharePoint to count the Document Sets in the KPI?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a CAML query?

```
<Where>
  <BeginsWith>
    <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
    <Value Type="ContentTypeId">0x0120D520</Value>
  </BeginsWith>
</Where>
```